# Period of small amplitude oscillations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

So I am trying to do a question where I have two objects that are rolling without slipping. We have found the potential function for this setup, have found the H, we are given y and we're also give the Icm in the problem. The small semi circle has mass m.
[image]

I have had many approaches to this question and can't seem to figure it out.

We know that the period formula is:
$$T= 2\pi\sqrt\frac{M}{U_{0}}$$

I know how to find the potential function, but I have zero clue what a generalized mass is.

I have searched it up and got even more confused as to what it means for finding the period of a generalized mass.